# Proving $Ind_H^G1_H=\pi_X$

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

**Lemma** Let $\psi=1_H$ the principal character of $H$, then $Ind_H^G1_H=\pi_X$, the permutation character of $G$ on the set $X$ of left cosets of $H$ in $G$.

**Proof** 
Let $\{t_i \}$ form a tranversal.
$$\begin{align}Ind_H^G1_H(g)&=\sum_i 1_H^{\circ}(t_i^{-1}gt_i) \\
&=|\{i: t_i^{-1}gt_i \in H \}| \\
&=|\{i: gt_i \in t_iH \}| \\
&=|\mathrm{fix}_X(g)|=\pi_X 
\end{align}$$
I do not see how we get $|\{i: gt_i \in t_iH \}|=|\mathrm{fix}_X(g)|$

I can figure it should be a stabiliser but I cannot see how this follows myself

Comment: The stabilizer of the coset $t_iH$ is $\{g \in G : gt_iH = t_iH \} = \{ g \in G : t_i^{-1}gt_i \in H \}$. (In the first two lines of your equations you have a $t_i^{-1}$ that should be $t_i$.)

Comment: How have you swapped from $g \in G$ from $i$ which belong to the indexing of the transversal?